# Does all error codes of WSASend() and WSARecv() means that the socket has disconnected?

Tags: c++, sockets, iocp

I need to know if the error codes of `WSASend()` and `WSARecv()` (except for `WSA_IO_PENDING`) when using IOCP means that the socket has disconnected. Most of the error codes are obvious, however I am not sure about the following:

Error codes of `WSASend()`:

- `WSAEINPROGRESS`
- `WSAENOBUFS`
- `WSA_OPERATION_ABORTED`

Error codes of `WSARecv()`:

- `WSAEFAULT`
- `WSAEINPROGRESS`

Comment: You might want to check [a list of the Winsock error codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), as well as read referenced for [`WSASend`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`WSARecv`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The Answer

No, not all error codes is because of a disconnected socket.

---

#### Elaboration

I'm actually not sure how to answer this question without yelling out *"No, read the documentation!"*.

- [**msdn.microsoft.com** - Windows Sockets Error Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

As an example, `WSAEINPROGRESS` means that there's another blocking operation in progress - so the current one has been aborted because of that.

> **`WSAEINPROGRESS`** - 10036
>
> > *Operation now in progress.*
> >
> > > A blocking operation is currently executing. Windows Sockets only allows a single blocking operation—per- task or thread—to be outstanding, and if any other function call is made (whether or not it references that or any other socket) the function fails with the WSAEINPROGRESS error.

Comment: **Could the down-voters clarify what is wrong with this answer?** OP states, explicitly, that he would like to know whether all relevant error codes denote that the socket has disconnected; the manual (and this answer) clearly states that this isn't the case.